# How to ignore choicepoints in prolog PL Unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, prolog

In prolog PL Unit testing, how can you ignore the warning messages that talk of choicepoints?

Thanks.

Comment: do you refer to SWI-Prolog PlUnit?

Comment: yes I am refering to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in SWI-Prolog [Unit Test](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%280,%270%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/plunit.html%27%29%29) there is the option `nondet`

> If this keyword appears in the option list, non-deterministic success of the body is not considered an error.

Comment: How do I use the nondet option?

Comment: `test('my test', nondet) :- my_predicate(...).`